# Form styles acting different in FF and Chrome

Tags: html, forms, css

I have a form that has an image behind it and in FF I can move the form lower and the image behind it stays where it is. But in Chrome the image and the form move together. Is there anyway I can get the form to move only in Chrome.

The code for the form is:

```
<div id="css">      
        <fieldset>  
<form action="contact.php" name="myForm" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm();">

    <input onfocus="this.value=''"" value="Name"
type="text" name="cf_name">


    <input onfocus="this.value=''"" value="Email" type="text" name="cf_email">

    <input onfocus="this.value=''"" value="Website"
type="text" name="cf_website">

    <textarea name="cf_message" onfocus="this.value=''""
    >Message</textarea>
<p class="submit">  <input type="submit" value="Send"></p>
</form>
</fieldset>
</div>
```

The CSS is:

```
#css fieldset
{
background: url(images/notepad_about1.png) no-repeat;
border:0px;
height:560px;
margin: 0; padding: 0;

}

#css input{

border-radius:5px;
border:medium none;
color:#000;
display:block;
font-size:2.75em;
width:450px;
margin:0 0 10px;
padding:8px;
cursor: default;
background-image: none;
background-color: #000cff;
opacity: 0.5;
}

#css form
{
margin-left:120px;
margin-top:30px;
}

#css textarea{
border-radius:5px;
border:medium none;color:#000;
display:block;
font-size:2.60em;
width:450px;
margin:0 0 10px;
padding:8px;
height:200px;
background-image: none;
background-color: #000cff;
opacity: 0.5;
font-family: Verdana,Arial,Sans-serif;
}

#css .submit input{ 
  background-color: #000;
   opacity: 9.5;
   font-size:1.75em;
   width:100px;
   color:#fff;
}

#css .submit input:hover{ 
  background-color: #000cff;
}
```

I currently have the image as a background in the `fieldset` tag. I then use the `#CSS form` to move just the form lower and this works in FF but in Chrome it moves the image and the form. Is there anyway to sort this out?

Thanks

Comment: You could add an image how it looks like in FF/Chrome. Or even better add a link to the example.

Comment: Also, just FYI, styling forms and form elements is notoriously difficult when trying to get the same look across browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `padding-top: 30px` instead of `margin-top: 30px` on the #css form

Comment: I'd also advise using `background: url(images/notepad_about1.png) top center no-repeat;`

Answer (score 0):

Although a `fieldset` element is syntactically allowed to contain a `form` element, such nesting is not common and generally not useful. I’d suggest nesting them the normal way, `form` containing `fieldset` (or maybe `div` – the `fieldset` is currently invalid as it contains no `legend` element, but this is mostly a formality). Then you can set the background on the `form` element and the displacement on the `fieldset` element, and this should work in a cross-browser way. Alternatively, you could use just `form` containing the fields directly and set a background image on `form` and suitable value for `padding-top` to create (what appears to be) the desired effect.